# Select radio button when clicked outside input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a standard Bootstrap 4 accordion with a radio button inside of it. Here is my code:

```
<div class="card"> 
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne"> 
        <h2 class="mb-0"> 
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tm-stripe-div" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="tm-stripe-div"> 
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"> 
                    <div class="stripe-payment-div"> 
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="paymentRadio" id="stripePayment" value=""> 
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="stripePayment"> Credit Card (Stripe) </label> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </button> 
        </h2> 
    </div> 
</div
```

When i click outside the input field the radio button is not selected. I know the best way would be to use jquery, but is there a way to do it with css only?

I'd like the radio button selected when the use clicks anywhere inside the `.card` class.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using JavaScript but if you really want to do it without, you can use the trick that a lot of custom form controls use.

Basically wrap it in a `label` and use the `for` attribute to point to your radio.

Had to also convert your `button` to an `a` because the clicks events weren't registering.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <label for="stripePayment" class="mb-0">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne"> 
        <h2 class="mb-0"> 
            <a class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tm-stripe-div" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="tm-stripe-div"> 
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"> 
                    <div class="stripe-payment-div"> 
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="paymentRadio" id="stripePayment" value=""> 
                        <span class="form-check-label" for="stripePayment"> Credit Card (Stripe) </span>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</h2>
</div>
</label>
</div>
```